# Post to Vertex AI My Prompt from Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-generativeai

I created a Vertex AI Generative Studio AI prompt.  I'm able to POST using CURL and get a response.  But when I try to create a Cloud Function I'm unable to get authorized.  Seems there is instructions on how to access your prompts from an application using the SDKs, but no instructions on doing it from Cloud Function as a server to server call.  Any help is appreciated

import os
from google.auth.transport import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import json
import requests as req

def vertex_ai_request(request):
# Define constants
API_ENDPOINT = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"
PROJECT_ID = "XXXX"
MODEL_ID = "text-bison@001"
URL = f"https://{API_ENDPOINT}/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/{MODEL_ID}:predict"

```
# Load the service account credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service-account-file.json'
)
auth_req = requests.Request()
token = credentials.refresh(auth_req).token

# Define the headers
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Define the payload
payload = {
    "instances": [
        {
            "content": "Your content here ..."
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "candidateCount": 1,
        "maxOutputTokens": 317,
        "temperature": 0.2,
        "topP": 0.8,
        "topK": 40
    }
}

# Send the POST request
response = req.post(URL, headers=headers, json=payload)

# Print the response to the logs
print(response.json())

return 'Request completed', 200
```

Comment: 1) Edit your post so that the Python code is formatted correctly. 2) Your code looks OK at first glance. What error are you getting? What are the IAM roles assigned to the service account?

Comment: I'm not to versed in authorization and roles.   I am using a service account but it doesn't look like it has an IAM role.  It has a Service Account Admin role.  What do you recommend?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control